# How to prove that given quotation is not a distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have function

$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x+y \geq 0, \\ 0, \text{ if } x+y<0  \end{cases}$.

I have no idea how can I prove that given quotation is not a distribution function. Only one think I know is $\Delta_sF \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(1,1)-F(1,-1)-F(-1,1)+F(-1,-1)=-1 <0$ so $F$ is not a distribution function. [In terms of random variable this means $P\{-1<X\leq 1,-1<Y\leq 1\} <0$!].

Comment: One more quostion. Why we take $-1$ instead $0$?

Comment: I know that you used $\Delta_s G= G(x_2,y_2)-G(x_1,y_2)-G(x_2,y_1)+G(x_1,y_1)$ From where I have to know how much  $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ is?

Comment: @Atstovas If you take $0$ instead of $1$ you won't get a contradiction.

Comment: so how to determine $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ from given function $F(x,y)$?

Comment: No thumb rule. You have to just play around with the function.